# How to set Banner ad in all activity?

Tags: android, banner-ads, admob

I am new in android app development and I am creating an app in android studio, which has 2 activities. One  is activity_main.xml which has a button to open second activity. When I set the banner ad it shows only on bottom of activity_main.xml and I want to set same banner ad in my second activity. What should I do. Please help me.thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to copy the ad banner view from `activity_main.xml` to your second activity's layout.

Also, please include code in your questions as it makes it easier for people to help you!

Comment: I copied and paste it in second activity but not working, can you tell me that  have I to do  something in Main_activity.java after copy paste the ad view.

Comment: Could you edit your original post with the layout code of your first and second activity as well as your Main_activity.java?

Comment: sorry,i am not able to add layout code to this question, when i try to add code an error comes that your code is not properly formatted as code. so i can't add my layout code.

Comment: haha alright so in your activity_main.xml at the bottom I assume there would be a layout that contains the ad layout right? It'd probably be an `AdView` or something similar. You'd just have to copy that to your second activity layout then initialise it in the second activity class.
For reference here's the official docs: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Answer (score 0):

Create a super class for `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity` by inheriting `Activity` class. call `integrateAdView()` from `onCreate()` method of child class.

`integrateAdView()` method of super class :

```
public void integrateAdView(){ 

    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM | android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);   
    addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ADV_PUB_ID);
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
       ...
    });
    layout.addView(adView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();    
    request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    adView.loadAd(request);   
}
```